# Python 'subprocess' gets stuck

Tags: python, subprocess

I use 'subprocess' to do work repeatedly like below.

```
import subprocess

arg_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for arg in arg_list:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['some_app.exe', arg])
    proc.communicate()
```

Most of runs terminates successfully but occasionally the app requires to click the 'OK' button. Then the script gets stuck there. A working time varies very widely depending on arguments('a', 'b', ...) so that I cannot set proper a timeout.

Is there any method to get processes' status(working or waiting for button clicked)? If I can tell the app is waiting for clicking then can terminate the process.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663743/python-subprocess-popen-send-click-on-ok) is a similar question but no solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any method to get processes' status(working or waiting for button clicked)? If I can tell the app is waiting for clicking then can terminate the process.

Not that I'm aware of. You can only check the process' running status using [proc.poll()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll). However, `proc.communicate()` is blocking, so you'll have to poll it in another thread.

**How to solve it?**

1. Kill after timeout

Note that [proc.communicate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) can get a `timeout` argument, so although *A working time varies very widely depending on arguments*, if you decide to calculate it - you can pass it and `subprocess` will kill the process for you after timeout.

2. Spam "enter"

I suggest you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564851/how-to-generate-keyboard-events) on how to send keyboard events. You might just want to add another thread that sends **enter** to your process every N seconds...

3. **optional (didn't check it)** psutil.status

Try using [psutil.status()](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=block#psutil.Process.status) [status options](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=block#process-status-constants) to check if your process is maybe `psutil.STATUS_SLEEPING`. Not sure how things work in Windows. If you were running on Linux I assume your process, if waiting for a keyboard key, would be `psutil.STATUS_IDLE` or `psutil.STATUS_WAITING`

Comment: `proc.poll` doesn't tell you that the program is waiting for a button to be clicked, only that it hasn't exited yet.

Comment: true. I read the `get processes' status` part and skipped the `(working or waiting for button clicked)`

Comment: @tdelaney and is that possible ?I thought checking the process' resource consumption but that is not definite. I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/27869588/3512538 might be a good solution on Linux, but don't know how to get the same result on Windows